# Question about Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

I try to understand why I get "Matrix dimensions must agree" error.
I checked the size of my matrices and they have matched inner dimensions 
[47, 2]*[2, 1] should be allowed.

```
    data = load('ex1data2.txt');
    X = data(:, 1:2);
    mu = mean(X)
    sigma = std(X)'

mu = mean(X)
sigma = std(X)'

[x_sizex, x_sizey] = size(X_norm);
[s_sizex, s_sizey] = size(sigma);

fprintf(' x row: %.0f, x column: %.0f, sigma x row: %.0f, sigma column: %.0f\n', [x_sizex, x_sizey, s_sizex, s_sizey]');

X ./ sigma
```

The error I get:

```
 x row: 47, x column: 2, sigma x row: 2, sigma column: 1
Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in debug (line 21)
X ./ sigma
```

Even using / operation and not ./ operation gives me the same error.

Comment: Do you want to multiply or divide? You are using element wise division `./`, when it should be matrix multiplication `*`.

Comment: I want to divide each row of X by the vector sigma

Comment: In that case, you have taken complex conjugate transpose of `std(X)` and stored it in `sigma`. You need to remove the complex conjugate transpose `'` (or take that again) for implicit expansion